# how do i insert button on my surface in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

i don't really understand how do i get my choice buttons over my backscreen.surface

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((520, 680))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("everlasting night")
main_font = pygame.font.Font("/Users//Desktop/dpcomic.ttf", 65)



backscreen_surface = pygame.image.load("//Users//Desktop/snow.jpeg")
text_surface = main_font.render("go home?", False, "Black")


# choice buttons(i deleted the code because it make 0 sense)

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.blit(backscreen_surface, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (140, 560))


    pygame.display.update()
```

i tried different ways but what i ger is an only button without backscreen.surface

Comment: Just blit the button image after the black screen image

Comment: The problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

In pygame draw in order so that

```py
screen.fill(...) # Background
pygame.draw.rect(...) # Draws on top
pygame.draw.rect(...) # Draws on top of both
# ... and so on
```

This will happend every frame, to make your code clearer I'd encourage you to have a draw function :

```py
def draw():
    # Your drawing code goes here
```

Now that you know that simply put the things in that order :

```py
def draw():
   # Fill you background
   # Draw anything that should be under the buttons
   # Draw your buttons
```

Your buttons will have multiple properties, for instance you may want to have `pos`, `size`, `background_color`, `text`.
Hence you should probably create a python dict to represent a button (or an class but I'm assuming you don't use classes yet)

For example, a button could look something like this :

```py
yes_button = {
    'pos': (0, 0), # x and y
    'size': (80, 40), # width and height
    'background_color': (0,255,0), # red, green and blue
    'color' : (255,255,255), # text color
    'text': 'yes'
}
```

And simply draw it like so :

```py
def draw():
   # ... your code before

    # Draw yes button (4 steps)
    # 1 - Create a rect object
    yes_button_rect = pg.Rect(
        yes_button['pos'],
        yes_button['size']
    )

    # 2 - Draw the button's background
    pg.draw.rect(
        screen,
        yes_button['background_color'],
        yes_button_rect
    )

    # 3 - Render the text
    button_text_render = main_font.render(
        yes_button['text'],
        False,
        yes_button['color']
    )

    # 4 - Center and draw the text
    button_center_x, button_center_y = yes_button_rect.center
    text_width, text_height = button_text_render.get_size() # get the width and height of your text
    button_text_x = button_center_x - text_width // 2
    button_text_y = button_center_y - text_height // 2
    screen.blit(button_text_render, (button_text_x, button_text_y))
```

## Go further :

If you care about performance you should pre-render and store your text inside the button dict, you can also pre-calculate the text drawing pos and store it in the button dict.  
For instance you could make a preload function :

```py
def preload_button(button):
    # Render the text and store it
    button['text_render'] = main_font.render(
        button['text'],
        False,
        button['color']
    )

    # Calc the button center pos
    button_top, button_left = button['pos']
    button_width, button_height = button['size']
    button_center_x = button_left + button_width // 2
    button_center_y = button_top + button_height // 2

    # Calc the pos to the draw the text at
    text_render_width, text_render_height = button['text_render'].get_size()
    text_x = button_center_x - text_render_width // 2
    text_y = button_center_y - text_render_height // 2
    button['text_pos'] = (text_x, text_y)
```

If you do so your draw code becomes :

```py
def draw():
    # ... your previous code

    # Draw yes button (2 steps)
    # 1 - Draw the button's background
    pg.draw.rect(
        screen,
        yes_button['background_color'],
        (yes_button['pos'], yes_button['size'])
    )

    # 2 - Draw the text
    screen.blit(yes_button['text_render'], yes_button['text_pos'])
```

Here I created just a yes button as an example but add as many as you want, placing them into a list :

```py
buttons = [yes_button, no_button, maybe_button, ...]
```

Now you can interact with them using a for each loop

```py
for button in buttons:
    # your code
```

Obviously making a button class would make everything way clearer but it's outside the scope of this answer

Happy programming